# can i add multiple value in field ? (please see an image)

Tags: forms

I need to do the stock management website with 2 Content type Supplier and Product.
First I add contents in Supplier content type. Then I add node reference field in Product content type and call it supplier and make it multiple value. it's looks good, i can select suppliers and save it. but in my concept i need to check which supplier sale this product and how price. so i need to add suppliers and price in the same form like my image,

[my concept image, create by photoshop, can i do like this ?](http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/9479/supplier.jpg)

the propose of this form, user can check how price of each supplier for this product and they can choose the lowest price for purchase in the next process.

Guys, did you have the idea that i can do like this ?

Thanks for share :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simmilar needs, i am using this module, for me it is very good! There are some other alternatives too, but for me this module is proven as stable:

http://drupal.org/project/double_field